# WPF datagrid double header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In WPF datagrid, is it possible to make the header look like the picture below? The example image was created in Excel. So the first header line are CURRENT and HIST. USAGE is a merged section, and second header line showing BOH, MIN, MAX etc.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

We can do with HierarchicalDataTemplates and apply to ItemsTemplate property of ItemsControl

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radtreeview/populating-with-data/hierarchical-data-templates

Comment: Can you give some details.e.g. sample codes? or links

Comment: I read the example on the link you provided.  It doesn't provide the function I am asking for.....anymore thoughts?